# How can I redirecting a cout-stream?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, cout

I've got an assignment I can't work out. I'm not asking for a complete solution but would be thankful if someone pointed me to the right direction:

There is a class to store Date-Values. It has a function displayDate().

```
class Date{
    int day, month, year;
public:
[...]
    virtual void displayDate(ostream &out=cout) const {
    out << getDay() << "." << getMonth()
            << "." << getYear() << endl;
    }
};
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const Date &dob) {
//?
}
```

The operator<< should be overloaded and should use the displayDate()-Function instead of having its own output-code.  How can I redirect the cout-stream of displayDate() so that I can use it in the operator<<-Function?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you skip the chapter on default parameters? You just need to pass the argument along.

Comment: You should just call `dob.displayDate` in your `operator<<`, and pass it the `os` argument.

Answer (score 2):

Just call displayDate on the passed object instance in the operator<<.

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & strm, MyClass const & o)
{
  o.someFunc(strm);
  return strm;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const Date &dob) {
    dob.displayDate(os);
}
```

Just spelling it out for you.
Notice that the default output stream for displayDate is std::cout. That is declared here:

```
virtual void displayDate(ostream &out=cout) const { ...
```

When you use this function within your operator << you are over-riding the default output stream with your reference 'os'.